# How listen for events in Hyperledger Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I haven't received any event notifications and am wondering if I am missing something.
I followed the instructions from the Fabric Composer website to define the BasicEvent in my cto model and added the code for creating and emitting events in a transaction and updated the network.  I created a separate eventListener.js program that subscribes to the events using the businessNetworkConnection using the code sample from the website.
After I start my eventListener.js app it seems to be listening (after receiving the connected status message in console, nothing else happens...it doesn't go back to the normal prompt line.)
I then execute the transaction that should emit the event and it runs successfully but no event is received in the other terminal window where the eventlistener.js is running.
Here is the key part of the eventListener.js program:

```js
businessNetworkConnection.connect(connectionProfile, businessNetworkIdentifier, participantId, participantPwd)
.then((result) => {
    businessNetworkDefinition = result;
    console.log('Connected: BusinessNetworkDefinition obtained=' + businessNetworkDefinition.getIdentifier());
  });
businessNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
    // event: { "$class": "org.namespace.BasicEvent", "eventId": "0000-0000-0000-000000#0" }
    console.log(event);
  });
```

Is the businessNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) ... command supposed to cause the program to appear to hang while its listening?
If so, is there something else that could be done to troubleshoot where the problem is?
I'm using v0.6 HLF on local Docker.

Comment: It shouldn't cause it to hang. You could try `DEBUG=composer:* node myApplication.js` to get some debug info.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you don't wait for the businessNetworkDefinition to be connected before you register your listener. Remember that the `then` block is executed asynchronously and your following `businessNetworkConnection.on` code will execute immediately.

You should add a second `then` block to register your listener *after* the businessNetworkDefinition has been connected.

e.g.

```
return adminConnection.connect('hlfv1', 'admin', 'adminpw')
    .then(() => {
        return BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));
    })
    .then((businessNetworkDefinition) => {
        return adminConnection.deploy(businessNetworkDefinition);
        // return true;
    })
    .then(() => {
        businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
        return businessNetworkConnection.connect('hlfv1', 'my-network', 'admin', 'adminpw');
    })
    .then(() => {
        businessNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
            console.log( '****** received the event ' + JSON.stringify(businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getSerializer().toJSON(event)));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code for a basic sample application developed by Hyperledger team. You can check out about from this code snippet: [SampleEventListener](https://github.com/aabdulwahed/composer-eventlistner)